# HTML <a> Native Click Event

Tags: javascript, html, click, native, href

Is there a way to programmatically within javascript call the native click event of an  tag? The .trigger('click') or .click() functions will not work, because they are triggering the onClick event of the link and not the event that follows the URL. I need to programmatically click a hidden link and follow that link to a new tab within the same browser. Window.open won't work either because that will cause a popup and I am trying to avoid that. I need this, because I am dynamically generating a URL on the server side and sending the responds back via JSON. I then populate the HREF attribute of the hidden link with the resulting URL. If I can get an answer on how this can be done, I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can tell, it is not possible to call the native click function of a link through javascript. You can reference the onclick by using .click(), but the native click will still run before that is called. So, if you wanted to alter the link before following it when you click the link, you would have to click the link twice before it would send you to the altered link.

Answer (score 2):

If you're populating a HREF with the JSON response, why not just store it in a variable instead, and when you want to go to it, `window.location = yourVariable;`?

Comment: window.location wont work for me, because I don't want to open the link in the current tab and replace the current page. I need it to go to a new tab.

Comment: Agreed, I don't see the point of assigning the URL to a hidden link just so you can click it. There are far more direct ways provided for navigating to a new location.

Comment: @usherjer If you want it to open in a new tab, use `window.open`. Whether that opens in a tab or a new window is entirely browser dependent as not all browsers support tabs. There is no way to specifically direct a browser to open a link in a new tab.

Comment: The reason I am trying to put it in a hidden link is because the functionality of the link click allows for a new tab to open while never replacing the current tab. If I use window.location, it replaces the current tab with the new URL.

Comment: @usherjer: There really isn't a guaranteed way to ensure that a link will be opened in a new tab, as the browser looks to it's internal settings for that option. If my browser is configured to open every link in the same window, your only other option is `window.open`.

Comment: I can use window.open, but I might need to open more than one tab/popup at a time and once I have a popup open, I can't seem to open another unless I close it first.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you want this to work on IE only, I don't have an answer for you, but I can tell you what the problem is.  The problem is `target=_blank`.  Try the following code as a test--notice it will bring you to Google.com--then try writing "_blank" in as the target.  That seems to be the only thing that the browsers won't allow.  A partial answer to your question is `fireEvent()` works with IE and `dispatchEvent()` works with everything else.  If anyone else could improve on this code, I would appreciate a better answer as well.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function fireElement() {
var target=document.getElementById('foobar');
if(document.dispatchEvent) { // W3C
var oEvent = document.createEvent( "MouseEvents" );
oEvent.initMouseEvent("click", true, true, window, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, false, false, false, false, 0, target);
target.dispatchEvent( oEvent );
}
else if(document.fireEvent) { // IE
target.fireEvent("onclick");
} 
}
</script>

</head>
<body>
<div>
<a id="foobar" target="" href="http://www.google.com"></a>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```